# Consulta SQL entre dos Tablas

Tags: sql, ms-access

Buen día! Mi pregunta a lo mejor es simple... pero llevo rato intentando y no logro dar con una solución... se mas o menos la teoría de lo que debería hacer pero no se específicamente como ejecutarlo.

Específicamente la consulta la estoy haciendo en Access pero debería funcionarme cualquier idea de respuesta en base a SQL

El esquema es:

Tengo una tabla con Muchísimos registros, de aquí hay un campo llamado "enlace" que es de X cantidad de longitud (puede ser 1 solo carácter o varios)

| Fecha | Enlace | Importe | Contrato |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/08 | 13315TYE857 | 500 | XXXXXXXX |
| 02/08 | 133152957YF | 700 | XXXXXXXX |
| 02/08 | 133140TT | 850 | XXXXXXXX |
| 02/08 | 890402X208 | 350 | XXXXXXXX |
| 02/08 | 89040292AR959 | 1600 | XXXXXXXX |
| 02/08 | PE20X8589349KDF | 2000 | XXXXXXXX |

Tengo otra tabla donde tengo una parametrización estructurada de la siguiente manera:

| Enlace | Pais |
| --- | --- |
| 13315 | España |
| 13314 | España |
| 890402 | Argentina |

etc...

Lo que necesito es que en base a estas dos tablas yo pueda consultar de la tabla que tiene todos los registros y extraer únicamente aquellos en donde el campo 'enlace' comience por los caracteres que tengo en el campo 'enlace' de la tabla de parametrización cuestion de que la consulta me quede tal que asi:

| Fecha | Enlace | Importe | Contrato | Pais |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/08 | 13315TYE857 | 500 | XXXXXXXX | España |
| 02/08 | 133152957YF | 700 | XXXXXXXX | España |
| 02/08 | 133140TT | 850 | XXXXXXXX | España |
| 02/08 | 890402X208 | 350 | XXXXXXXX | Argentina |
| 02/08 | 89040292AR959 | 1600 | XXXXXXXX | Argentina |

No lo he podido hacer con un Join de ambos campos enlace porque en la tabla principal el enlace es mucho mas largo sin embargo siempre empezara por Equis caracteres cuando pertenezca a un pais u otro.

Tampoco puedo hacerlo comparando los primeros 5 caracteres porque aveces el enlace de la parametria es mas largo que 5 caracteres.

Lo siento si algo no se entiende.

Comment: Tu error es de diseño. ¿Qué justifica un diseño tan complicado, poco eficiente y muy difícil de mantener? Tarde o temprano tendrás que normalizar esto o tu sistema terminará siendo leeento con el tiempo, o no soportará futuros requerimientos y/o estará manejando datos erróneos. Dicho eso, explica mejor la cosa aportando un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable.

Comment: No soy experto en la materia.

Comment: ¿Qué representa `Enlace` y cuál es su relación con `Pais`? La cuestión es que si el error es de diseño, podrías estar intentando resolver mediante un código chapuza un problema que está a otro nivel más bajo y mientras no lo resuelvas a ese nivel, estarás poniendo parches hasta que todo explote, pudiendo tener consecuencias catastróficas.

Comment: Enlace es un Código que Representa a Pais.... Es decir en la tabla principal Donde enlace comience por 13315 siempre va a ser España, siempre que empiece por 890402 va a ser Argentina y asi...

Comment: Pero claro en la tabla principal "Enlace" puede ser por ejemplo 13315X0296 (siendo esto España) pero en otro registro "Enlace" es 13315OE1204 (siendo tambien españa) ... Es decir cada vez que empiece por 13315 españa, cada vez que empiece por 13314 tambien es españa.  "Enlace" es un codigo de identificación del registro pero para saber a que pais pertenece necesito verificar con mi otra tabla de parametria que es la que coloco en el ejemplo.

Comment: "No lo he podido hacer con un Join de ambos campos enlace porque"... "Tampoco puedo hacerlo comparando los primeros 5 caracteres porque"... pon en la pregunta lo que intentaste y con qué datos falla

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no lo he podido hacer de esa forma no porque falle si no porque se que no es la manera correcta debido a las características que indico en la propia pregunta jeje

Comment: ¿Y qué son los valores como `TYE857`, `2957YF`, etc? Parecen un intento de meter en una misma columna más de un dato, con la aparente ventaja de *ahorrar*  ¿? Cuando hablo de errores de diseño me refiero a cosas como estas. En un principio pudo parecer una idea genial: ¡dos campos en uno! Ahora los problemas empiezan a sacar la cabeza cuando el contexto se complica sólo un poquito.

Comment: Lastimosamente eso no depende ya de mi... Yo solo trato de hacer una consulta sobre algo que ya existe de esa manera. En todo caso ya doy por solventada la pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saquemos de encima el problema de que ese diseño es simplemente malo.

Una vez que dijimos eso, sabias que en un join podes usar absolutamente cualquier expresion que implique la igualacion de dos campos???

Asi que, simplemente, vamos a probar hacer el join usando like!

Como no tengo access, y no dejaste un fiddle para probarlo, vamos a suponer que esto funciona (por que en ANSI sql funciona).

```
select los campos que quieras
from Tabla1 
    inner join Tabla2 ON Tabla1.Enlace LIKE Tabla2.Enlace + "*"
```

donde `tabla1` seria la tabla que tiene el enlace largo, y `tabla2` la del enlace mas corto, sin importar el tamaño.

Hay otra forma de hacer esto, y es para evitar el join si access protesta.

Igual, dependiendo de donde lo pones, access puede llegar a protestar igual.

Podrias hacer un subquery solamente para ese campo, de la siguiente forma:

```
select tus otros campos,
    (select pais from la otra tabla as t where a.enlace like t.enlace + "*") as pais
from la primer tabla
```

Los nombres son todos inventados, porque ni eso pusiste en tu publicacón :(

Igual, vuelvo a repetir, es un muy mal diseño, y si recien estas empezando, tiralo a la basura y empeza de vuelta.